# Print information from Wikipedia

Tags: perl, wikipedia

Im trying to print out information from Wikipedia and it does: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv5dt.png

This is the code I'm using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Wikipedia;
use HTML::Restrict;

my $wiki = WWW::Wikipedia->new(clean_html => 1);
my $hr = HTML::Restrict->new;
my $entry = $wiki->search('Perl');
my $processed = $hr->process($entry->text_basic);
print $processed;

1;
```

Im hoping to remove the stuff above "perl is a family" and print out only the paragraphs.

Example it prints this out:

```
     {{Infobox programming language
 | name                   = Perl
 | logo                   = 
 | paradigm               = multi-paradigm: functional, imperative, object-oriented (class-based), reflective, procedural, event-driven, generic
 | year                   = 
 | designer               = Larry Wall
 | developer              = Larry Wall
 | latest_release_version = 5.22.1
 | latest_release_date    = 
 | latest_preview_version = 5.23.7
 | latest_preview_date    = 
 | turing-complete        = Yes
 | typing                 = Dynamic
 | influenced_by          = AWK, Smalltalk 80, Lisp, C, C++, sed, Unix shell, Pascal
 | influenced             = Chapel, Coffeescript, ECMAScript/JavaScript, Falcon, Julia, LPC, Perl 6, PHP, Python, Qore, Ruby, Windows PowerShell
 | programming_language   = C
 | operating_system       = Cross-platform
 | license                = GNU General Public License or Artistic License
 | website                = 
 | file_ext               = .pl .pm .t .pod
 | wikibooks              = Perl Programming
 }}

'Perl' is a family of high-level, general-purpose, interpreted, dynamic programming languages. The languages in this family include Perl 5 and Perl 6.

Though Perl is not officially an acronym, there are various backronyms in use, the most well-known being "Practical Extraction and Reporting Language". Perl was originally developed by Larry Wall in 1987 as a general-purpose Unix scripting language to make report processing easier. Since then, it has undergone many changes and revisions. Perl 6, which began as a redesign of Perl 5 in 2000, eventually evolved into a separate language. Both languages continue to be developed independently by different development teams and liberally borrow ideas from one another.

The Perl languages borrow features from other programming languages including C, shell script (sh), AWK, and sed. They provide powerful text processing facilities without the arbitrary data-length limits of many contemporary Unix commandline tools, facilitating easy manipulation of text files. Perl 5 gained widespread popularity in the late 1990s as a CGI scripting language, in part due to its unsurpassed  regular expression and string parsing abilities.

 In addition to CGI, Perl 5 is used for graphics programming, system administration, network programming, finance, bioinformatics, and other applications. It has been nicknamed "the Swiss Army chainsaw of scripting languages" because of its flexibility and power, and possibly also because of its "ugliness".  In 1998, it was also referred to as the "duct tape that holds the Internet together", in reference to both its ubiquitous use as a glue language and its perceived inelegance.
```

I want to remove:

```
 {{Infobox programming language
 | name                   = Perl
 | logo                   = 
 | paradigm               = multi-paradigm: functional, imperative, object-oriented (class-based), reflective, procedural, event-driven, generic
 | year                   = 
 | designer               = Larry Wall
 | developer              = Larry Wall
 | latest_release_version = 5.22.1
 | latest_release_date    = 
 | latest_preview_version = 5.23.7
 | latest_preview_date    = 
 | turing-complete        = Yes
 | typing                 = Dynamic
 | influenced_by          = AWK, Smalltalk 80, Lisp, C, C++, sed, Unix shell, Pascal
 | influenced             = Chapel, Coffeescript, ECMAScript/JavaScript, Falcon, Julia, LPC, Perl 6, PHP, Python, Qore, Ruby, Windows PowerShell
 | programming_language   = C
 | operating_system       = Cross-platform
 | license                = GNU General Public License or Artistic License
 | website                = 
 | file_ext               = .pl .pm .t .pod
 | wikibooks              = Perl Programming
 }}
```

I only want to display the paragraphs from each search result.

Comment: Why dont you state a sample of the string returned from the wiki, and indicate what part you wish to remove exactly. Then we may be able to give you a regex that do the job for you.

Comment: There done. Sorry it took a while as im on a phone and this is actually for a friend.

Comment: This better, thanks. Please find my answer below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the string returned by the wiki against a regex to replace the first part which is between {{}} and the empty new lines right after it, by empty string:

`$processed =~ s/\{\{.*\}\}\R\R//s;`

As you can see I used the `/s` option to match multiple lines and I didnt use the `g` option so that we replace the first greedy match only.

Comment: Works perfectly, just when I try other search words, it displays things above the starting of the first paragraph

Comment: By things you mean extra text outside the {{}} that you also want to remove?

Comment: When I try for example, the word "cement". This is what it prints out: goggles, and protective gloves, unlike the worker pictured herehttp://www.hse.gov.uk/pubns/cis26.pdfhttp://www.cementaustralia.com.au/wps/wcm/connect/website/packaged-products/home/hints-and-tips/FAQ-Safety/#FAQ-safety-PPE.htmlhttp://www.tdi.texas.gov/pubs/videoresource/stpcement.pdf]]
A 'cement' is a binder, a substance that sets and hardens and can bind other materials together. The word "cement" can be traced back to the Roman term [[opus caementicium]], used to describe masonry resembling modern concrete that was

Comment: I'm not sure if there is way to match all possible returned Strings. I can't see any rule for it.

Comment: I found this, but its in php

Comment: // remove `{{cite}}` tags
$str = preg_replace('/\s*\{\{[^}{]*+\}\}\s*/', ' ', $str);

// remove links--including rollover text--leaving link text
$str = preg_replace('/\[\[(?:[^][|]*+\|)?+([^][]*+)\]\]/', '$1', $str);